# How to save PWA state in IOS after closing the tab?

Tags: javascript, ios, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, manifest.json

I have a PWA that works great on Android. It’s a game from a distribution site embedded into my HTML in an iframe. On Android, when you open the game and play it, then close the tab and reopen the PWA, it saves your progress.

This doesn’t work on Safari.

I know Safari [now saves the PWA state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331758/how-to-save-pwa-state-in-ios) when you open another tab, but this question is about after the tab is completely closed.

I think this is close to what I’m looking for, but I’m not sure how to implement it for my entire html page:

https://www.netguru.com/blog/how-to-share-session-cookie-or-state-between-pwa-in-standalone-mode-and-safari-on-ios

How do you save PWA state in IOS after closing the tab?

Comment: is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517747/how-can-i-make-an-pwa-work-exactly-like-it-does-in-a-browser-but-keep-fullscree - someone elses game in an iframe?

Comment: @Bravo yes, it’s related. I’ve since found out that it’s not the PWA in general, but a problem with Safari.